# initializing UIView subclass with parameters in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Iam a newbiew to iPhone development. Version of my SDK is 2.2

In my code, UIViewController is used to change view dynamically once the app is launched, a method in the UIViewController is called to know which view should be initialized along with parameters, which goes to a 'switch-case' and assign a view to current view according to the parameter, like this:

```
    case 1:
        currentView = [[View01 alloc] init];
        break;
    case 2:
        currentView = [[View02 alloc] init];
        break;
```

and outside the switch-case:

```
[self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
```

I wonder f can pass a parameter along with initialization, like iniWithNibName or so? I need this because have to manipulate in the leaded view, according to the view from which its called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to modify your View01 and View02 classes to include an initWithParam: initialiser.

i.e. add

```
- (id) initWithParam:(NSString *)myParam;
```

to the @interface section and add

```
- (id) initWithParam:(NSString *)myParam {
  if (self = [self init]) {
    // handle or store 'myParam' somewhere for use later
  }

  return self;
}
```

to the @implementation section. Notice how the initWithParam: message internally calls the existing init. Obviously you could change the type, or number of parameters passed in as required.

Another approach would be to provide a property on your view class, so you could do something like the following:

```
currentView = [[View01 alloc] init];
currentView.myParam = @"SomeValue";
```

Which approach works the best will depend somewhat on your particular application needs.

Comment: I was doing it like your second way, first one is what exactly I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: you could have initWithParam and also the property in case you need to change the initial value set.